# What are the most important topics to study before going to university?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, advice

I would like to go to university next year as a mathematics undergraduate and so I want to be as prepared as I can. I am currently reading Velleman's "How to Prove It" in order to get a better understanding of proofs, however I am not really sure about what I should study next ? Set theory, calculus, real analysis, linear algebra ? Also some books recommendations for the topics you suggest would be really appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no most important/required topics to study, besides proofs. After study an intro to proofs text like Velleman (btw I recommend the text at https://infinitedescent.xyz/), pick whatever interests you.

Relating to university requirements, most likely they'll have you take abstract algebra, linear algebra, topology, and real analysis at minimum, even if they don't interest you.

Some nonrequired topics are [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory), [foundations of math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics), [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), and [discrete maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics).

Comment: I am not too worried about abstract and linear algebra as they are the topics that interest me the most. :-)